# Piping output from one program to another not working for this particular program

Tags: c++, linux, stdout, stdin, pipe

I expect this is a basic question, but I haven't been able to find an answer.

I'm building a web server in C++, and in order to help me visualise the system as it's running I'm building a separate program to do the visualisation. The web server will inform the visualiser of its current state by printing statements to stdout that are piped into the visualiser, which will parse the input and render a nice schematic view of the whole system along with various stats. The visualiser will be written in Python.

To check that I understand how piping works I created two simple programs:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


int main() {
    cout << "Hello world!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

, and

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


int main() {
    char buf[128];

    while (!cin.eof()) {
        cin.getline(buf, 128, '\n');
        cout << "Received line: " << buf << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This works as expected when I execute the command

```
./one | ./two
```

However, when I run my web server like so:

```
./aril | ./two
```

I get no output at all.

Running the server on its own produces output like the following:

```
Spawning handlers
Waiting for HTTP clients
Server: got connection from 127.0.0.1, port 52168
Connection timed out
```

(Obviously that isn't actually the kind of output I'll be passing to the visualiser -- it will need a more easily parse-able syntax).

Possibly relevant info:

The web server is divided into two processes: aril and arild. aril runs with root privileges, whereas arild doesn't. Both processes print to stdout using std::cout.

I can't think of any reason why this isn't working.

EDIT:
The solution, it turns out, is simply to explicitly flush the output. Should have been the first thing I tried really..

Comment: Unrelated: Prefer `std::string` and `std::getline` for reading lines from `std::cin`.

Comment: Maybe ./aril is writing to stderr?  Try ./aril 2>&1 | ./two

Comment: Are you sure  your web server prints to stdout, not stderr ? Have you tried ./aril 2>&1 |./two ?

Comment: Wow Brent Washburne. Great minds think alike :)

Comment: @BrentWashburne Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't fix the problem. As mentioned, the server is using std::cout, and its output appears in the terminal as expected when it's executed on its own.

Comment: Hmm maybe aril's output lines are not terminated by \n and it is using \r instead ? 
Or, perhaps it is actively trying to prevent piping ? By messing with the command line maybe ?

Comment: So, the code you showed works just fine, and it's the code you **didn't** show that you have questions about? How is that supposed to work?

Comment: You might check what syscalls (strace) is aril using to print it's logs. It might be that it's opening `dev/tty` to print to terminal anyway, or just checking if output goes to terminal, and give output only if it does. Just try `./aril 2>&1 >> tmp.log` and see if anything lands in your log. If it doesn't, it means you will be unable to use pipes to catch output.

Comment: You might also check if `./aril` is flushing it's output - this might also be dependent on if output is a terminal or not.

Comment: @j_kubik Yes, it turns out the problem was as simple as that. It appears that I have to explicitly flush the output for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Your web server is printing in STDERR while in `two` you are reading from STDIN. So it'll not work.

Change `./aril | ./two` to

```
./aril 2>&1 | ./two
```

This will redirect all the STDERR and STOUT of `aril` to STDOUT and thus `two` will be able to read it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that aril detects if its output is piped (see fstat() and this thread http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/73909-prevent-piping.html for details) and switches to silent mode, i.e does not produce any output. Try piping to something else, cat maybe, and see if it produces an output.

Answer (score -1):

I think your programs are designed to work as pairs, but not interchangeably.  `./one | ./two` are an example of piping, but `./aril` is expecting to communicate with `./arild` via sockets.  It probably doesn't make sense to mix `./aril | ./two`.

Comment: `./aril` and `./arild` are communicating via sockets, but whatever `./aril` reads from it's end of the socket, it's probably putting on standard output to be read by `./two`, so this combination does make sense.

Comment: In that case, run ./aril|./two& in the background, and then run ./arild in parallel (or run them in separate terminal windows).

Comment: It's guessing on my part here, but I was assuming that's what he was doing already.